# Email Alert to be sent when a Qlik Sense Server Tasks fails using Zabbix Monitoring Software

Tags: zabbix, qliksense

I'm trying to monitor my qlik sense server tasks using zabbix and incase of any task failure I want to trigger a email citing the failure. I'm currently facing the following issues:

1. Enabling SNMP protocol in the Qlik Sense Server
2. post the integration how the QMC parameters are brought into zabbix
   application

This is my first  time working in integration so kindly let me know if you have any idea or suggestions on how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: I have some tasks which will running in the QMC of the Qlik Sense Server. These tasks are mainly used to load the data. Incase this task failed due to some error like timed out error. I want Zabbix monitoring software to monitor these tasks and send an alert mail incase of task failure.

Comment: These mails can be triggered by writing a condition in the form of template in zabbix. For that I have to establish a connection between Qlik and Zabbix using SNMP protocol

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Zabbix, but you can use QRS REST API to get the list of tasks with their status.
the endpoint is:

/qrs/executionresult/full

or

/qrs/executionresult/{taskid}

the status comes as an integer whose values are as follow:

0, 'NeverStarted'
1, 'Triggered'
2, 'Running'
3, 'Queued'
4, 'AbortInitiated'
5, 'Aborting'
6, 'Aborted'
7, 'FinishedSuccess'
8, 'FinishedFailed'
9, 'Skipped'
10, 'Retry'
11, 'Error',
12, 'Reset'

For info, I built such mechanism directly in a Qlik Sense application using Qlik REST connector.

The Qlik application is calling another REST API when detecting such a problem and this fires an incident in our system.